# How to get signature of Data constructor in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
{- Define an employee type -}
data Employee = Engineer {name :: String, engineerId :: String}
                | Manager {name :: String, managerId :: Integer}
                | Director {name :: String, directorId :: Integer}
                deriving Show
```

I defined a variable engineer1 like below.

```
*Main> let engineer1 = Engineer "Hari" "123"
```

When I query for type of engineer1, it gives me like "engineer1 :: Employee". I understood that, Engineer is data constructor, where as Employee is corresponding type constructor. My question is, is there any way that I can get signature of data constructor like "Engineeer String String" :: Employee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function like:

```
typeEmployee :: Employee -> String
typeEmployee (Engineer _ _) = "..."
typeEmployee (Manager _ _) = "..."
typeEmployee (Director _ _) = "..."
```

Other option, create a new class `ShowType`:

```
-- TYPE
data Employee a b = Engineer {name :: a, engineerId :: b}
                | Manager {name :: a, managerId :: b}
                | Director {name :: a, directorId :: b}
                deriving Show

-- CLASS
class ShowType a where
    showType :: a -> String

-- INSTANCES
instance ShowType Int where
    showType _ = "Int"

instance ShowType Integer where
    showType _ = "Integer"

instance ShowType Float where
    showType _ = "Float"

instance ShowType Char where
    showType _ = "Char"

instance (ShowType a) => ShowType [a] where
    showType x = "[" ++ showType (head x) ++ "]"

instance (ShowType a, ShowType b) => ShowType (Employee a b) where
    showType (Engineer x y) = "Engineer " ++ showType x ++ ' ' : showType y
    showType (Manager x y) = "Manager " ++ showType x ++ ' ' : showType y
    showType (Director x y) = "Director " ++ showType x ++ ' ' : showType y
```

Now, You can do:

```
*Main> showType (Manager 12 "a")
"Manager Integer [Char]"

*Main> showType (Manager [56] 12)
"Manager [Integer] Integer"

*Main> let x = Engineer 12 5 :: (Employee Int Int)
*Main> showType x
"Engineer Int Int"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It solves the problem, Is there any inbuilt function to do this ? because, incase of custom types with type variables, it is difficult to manage.

Comment: Check my answer again. @HariKrishna

Answer (score 2):

```
*Main> :t Engineer 
Engineer :: String -> String -> Employee
```

Note that `Employee` is a type, not a data constructor.

Comment: By querying like ":t Engineer", i can get the singature of data constructor. But  i am looking for, how to get this by querying variable 'engineer1' itslef.

Comment: You'd have to write a `case` statement to figure out which data constructor it used, but there's no easy way to get the type of something from inside the body of the case statement. `:t` is a ghci command rather than something you can run inside a Haskell expression.